# Android Dynamic RadioGroup

Tags: android, dynamic, radio-group

I'm trying to make a equalizer RadioGroup. And I wan to dynamically add radio button for presets.

Here is my layout XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rgEqualizerPreset"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

And Here is the Java code:

```
RadioGroup rgEqualizer;
List<RadioButton> radioButtonList;
MediaPlayer mPlayer;
Equalizer mEqualizer;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.equalizer);
    rgEqualizer = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgEqualizerPreset);

    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mEqualizer = new Equalizer(0, mPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
    rgEqualizer = new RadioGroup(this);
    radioButtonList = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();

    fillRadioGroupWithRadioButtons();
    rgEqualizer.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
}

private void fillRadioGroupWithRadioButtons() {

    Short noPresets = mEqualizer.getNumberOfPresets();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < noPresets) {
        RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(this);
        rb.setText(mEqualizer.getPresetName((short) i));
        layoutParams = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
                RadioGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                RadioGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        rgEqualizer.addView(rb, layoutParams);
        i++;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

When this activity opens nothing is displayed only blank layout screen.
What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the obvious already? I.e., that `getNumberOfPresets()` returns something > 0

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that rgEqualizer is not actually the RadioGroup in your layout.  You probably meant:

```
rgEqualizer = (RadioGroup) this.findViewById(R.id.rgEqualizerPreset);
```

in place of:

```
rgEqualizer = new RadioGroup(this);
```

So your radio buttons are getting added just fine, they just have nothing to do with your layout.  I feel your pain.

Comment: Good troubleshooting. Actually, the OP had both of those statements, but the latter was overwriting the former. I think if you had this problem in Android Studio, it would show you a warning that the first value was never used (but that warning is easy to miss).